# Retrieving user info & add info in columns using VBA form

Tags: excel, vba, forms

We have a file with patient details.

What we want to achieve is have a VBA form that a user can search using patients name and view fields Hospital no and D.O.B. - It works but based on a numeric field.

After finding the patient use the form to add extra info to specific columns for that patient.

```
'Declaring variables

Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

'Code to retrieve data based on ID - to be changed to string ( patients name 
)

Sub GetData()

If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
flag = False
i = 0
id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
        flag = True
        For j = 2 To 3
            UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        Next j
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

If flag = False Then
    For j = 2 To 3
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
End If

'Else
 '   ClearForm
End If

End Sub

'Sub to Add extra fields on the selected patient

Sub EditAdd()

Dim emptyCol As Long

If UserForm1.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
flag = False
i = 0
id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
'emptyCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:Z")) + 1
emptyCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) + 1
Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
        flag = True
        For j = 2 To 3
            Cells(i + 1, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
        Next j
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

If flag = False Then
    For j = 1 To 3
        Cells(emptyCol, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
    Next j
End If

End If

End Sub
```

This is how the form looks ( Textbox1 to Textbox10 from top to bot.
Column names that the data should be added are as in the form:
Initials,Date,Date of Death,Cause of death,Date of cardiac event, Type of cardiac event,Comment

[image]

Here is an example of how it works currently based on numeric search 
[image]

Comment: And the question is...? Do you want to make it work on a text field instead of numeric field? Should we guess your question?

Comment: Sorry should make it more clear 
1) Yes the textbox1 should work as a text field.
2) The Patient name is the search box and Hospital No and D.O.B will be populated. The rest of the boxes will be the input of the user for that patient hope that makes sense

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match? Can you please post some example for the string match?

Comment: Yes it should be an exact match of the patients name in the Patient name column.

Can't give out the patients name hope you understand but can use any name

Comment: Then you should use a combobox instead of a textbox. You should populate your combobox using the range in Patient name column. When the combobox is selected, it can return the selected value's row number. You can use this row number to do rest of your work.

Comment: There are few thousand names to be listed in a combo box..

Comment: A few thousand entries should be ok. Side note: If you don't know already, users do not necessarily scroll down to find the patient name. Users can type in combobox and the closest match will appear in the combobox while typing. (If this what you mean by a few thousand entries. I got it memory wise.)

Comment: Would be possible to give me an example based on the code as i am not following completely i think.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html), there are lots of tuts on the net.